# how to get all the information of maps in ArcGIS online

Tags: html, rest, web-crawler, arcgis, arcgis-server

I'm using ArcGIS REST API and would like to retrieve information about the maps in the ArcGIS online gallery.

For example, I want all the information from this page:`http://doc.arcgis.com/en/living-atlas/item/?itemId=aa9c87d6f17b452296252bd75005f6a4` This is for one map

I know each map has an itemID, but they have tons of maps in this page:`http://doc.arcgis.com/en/living-atlas/#s=0&subCat=0&type=All&area=All`, how do I get all the map IDs from it? Is there a REST service to do that? I didn't find one in their REST API reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That [page that you're referencing](http://doc.arcgis.com/en/living-atlas/#s=0&subCat=0&type=All&area=All) is using the [ArcGIS REST API](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcgis-rest-api). If you look at the network panel of your browser console, you'll see first it's [searching for all the groups that have the tag of "gallery" and the owner is `esri OR Esri_cy_US`](https://www.arcgis.com/sharing/rest/community/groups?f=json&q=tags%3A%22gallery%22%20AND%20owner%3A(esri%20OR%20Esri_cy_US)&_=1468887598765) using the [groups search endpoint](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcgis-rest-api/#/Group_Search/02r3000000m1000000/):

[image: groups query]

Then it takes those groups and finds all the items in those groups using the [search endpoint](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcgis-rest-api/#/Search/02r3000000mp000000/):

[image: search items in groups]

Good luck using the REST API!